# Java EE 6 Study Material

Tags: java-ee-6

I'm looking at doing one of the Java EE 6 certifications but I'm struggling to find out what study material is available to meet the exam objectives. Other certifications I've done I have just bought a book to prepare for the exam. The company I work for also has a certification program where they will pay for basic study material and the exam, but I think I can safely assume that one of Oracle's 5 day courses costing in the region of $3000 is out of the question.

I know it's very early in the game as most of the exams are still in beta testing but does any one know if there is any worthy study material to prepare for the exams or perhaps when some will be available. I'm leaning towards the JPA or JavaServer Pages and
Servlet Developer certifications.

Comment: This has been a problem for years as far as I know. e.g. there is still no book for SCBCD 1.5 AFAIK. The main problem being that those who have the required skills have better (read: better paid) things to do than write books, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I've never done such a certification, but wouldn't the official [Java EE 6 tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/) from Oracle be a sound basis for preparation?